# Incompatible pointer types on array initialization

Tags: c, arrays, constants

The following array initializer:

```
const char** AST_NODE_TYPE_NAMES = {
    "AST_NODE_CONSTANT",
    "AST_NODE_BINARY",
    "AST_NODE_UNARY",
    "AST_NODE_VARIABLE",
    "AST_NODE_ASSIGNMENT",
    "AST_NODE_STATEMENTS",
};
```

Makes `gcc` raise the following warning:

```
initialization of 'const char **' from incompatible pointer type 'char *'
```

Help me figure this out?

Comment: Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: ... but you've written an initializer for `AST_NODE_TYPE_NAMES` as if it were an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want array of pointers

```
const char *AST_NODE_TYPE_NAMES[] = {
    "AST_NODE_CONSTANT",
    "AST_NODE_BINARY",
    "AST_NODE_UNARY",
    "AST_NODE_VARIABLE",
    "AST_NODE_ASSIGNMENT",
    "AST_NODE_STATEMENTS",
};
```

and this array can eventually decal to the pointer you want:

```
const char **foo1 = AST_NODE_TYPE_NAMES;
const char **foo = &AST_NODE_TYPE_NAMES[0];
```

you can also use the compound literal (which actually is the array of pointers in this case) to initialize this pointer

```
const char** AST_NODE_TYPE_NAMES =(const char *[]) {
    "AST_NODE_CONSTANT",
    "AST_NODE_BINARY",
    "AST_NODE_UNARY",
    "AST_NODE_VARIABLE",
    "AST_NODE_ASSIGNMENT",
    "AST_NODE_STATEMENTS",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is not an **aggregate** but a scalar, and it expects *one* value to initialize it. In C it is also permissible to wrap the scalar initializer in `{ }`!

Thus:

```
const char** AST_NODE_TYPE_NAMES = {
     "AST_NODE_CONSTANT",
     "AST_NODE_BINARY",
     "AST_NODE_UNARY",
     "AST_NODE_VARIABLE",
     "AST_NODE_ASSIGNMENT",
     "AST_NODE_STATEMENTS",
};
```

tries to initialize *one* pointer to pointer to const char with the address of the first character of string literal `"AST_NODE_CONSTANT"`, but that does not have type `const char **` but just `char *`. In addition to *that*, there are *5 excess initializers*, namely the following strings.

---

What you of course want to do is to initialize an array, as [P__J__](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56090872/918959) already showed.